# Display form on template

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name

class SupplierOrder(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    numero_invoice = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have this form:

```
class SupplierOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SupplierOrder
```

In pass a supplier order form to a template in which I have this code:

```
<table>
{% for f in forms %}
    {% for field in f.visible_fields %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ field.value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that for supplier it display the supplier id, but I want the supplier name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forloop's `field` value is an instance of BoundField:

```
{% for field in f.visible_fields %}
```

You can get the value of a BoundField instance as such:

```
boundfield.field.to_python(boundfield.value())
```

So you could [make a trivial template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def to_python(boundfield):
    return boundfield.field.to_python(boundfield.value())
```

And use it in your template:

```
{% load your_template_tags %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ field|to_python }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method to your model:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name
```

Comment: What about displaying `<td>{{ field.data }}</td>` ?